# Add folder to solution explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2010

How i can add folder with all files and subfolders to my project in solution explorer?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Click on Solution Explorer Show All Files. Right click on folder. Include in Project.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to successfully add a new folder to a project.  I personally like to add new folders via Source Control Explorer

Step 1 - Create new folder via Source Control Explorer

[image: Create New folder via Source Control Explorer]

Step 2 - Select 'Show All Files' to display new folder in solution explorer
[image: Show All Files]

Step 3 - Include folder in project
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Get latest.  Modify the folders in your C: Drive, or wherever you put the objects from the solution. In the solution explorer click on Show All files (Thanks x2, this helped me so much!)  Right click to Include in Project.

This helped me to add new schemas with all their subfolders while avoiding the problems with Writing updates...