# Solution folder not shown in windows explorer

Tags: html, visual-studio-2010, projects-and-solutions, windows-explorer

I opened a blank solution in Visual Studio (2010).

I added a folder in solution and within a `Html` file.

In Window Explorer, the file is added to the solution level and not within a folder.

Also, it did not created folder at all.

I tried to add the folder manually in Window Explorer and then re-add a file. It did not help still the file is not added to the folder, but at the Solution level.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431605/add-folder-to-solution-explorer

Comment: @Longball27. See the comment of fretje.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add folder to solution explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431605/add-folder-to-solution-explorer)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Solution folders in VS are only visible within VS and are not file system folders.

If you want a file system folder to be mirrored in VS then you will need to create the folder on the file system and then use the 'Add/Existing Item' option to add the folder.

You can then add a file to this folder and it will appear where you would expect it to.

Comment: I can't add a folder like item to the solution.

Comment: If the folder exists on the filesystem then you can reveal it to VS by clicking on the 'Show All Files' icon at the top of Solution Explorer. Once you can see it, right-click and 'Include in Project'

Comment: Show All files icon appears only on projects. not on blank solution

Comment: Then you will need to create a solution folder and also create a filesystem folder and Add/Existing Item to the folder that way.