# Cannot add source code files to a Windows Forms application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I'm trying add some code from another project into the windows form application project by copying and pasting a folder. (the folder contains some .cs files). However, I cannot see the project in the solution explorer and I cannot use any of those codes. This copy-paste process works for C# console application but it doesn't work for windows form applications.

How can I add the codes into the project?

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431605/add-folder-to-solution-explorer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Most probably because you're using .NET Framework VS .NET Core:**

On these, additionally to copying files, you **must** include them in the project with *Add Existing Item*:

[image]

On these, copying files to directory will be sufficient:

[image]

In short, they use a newer, improved format of `.csproj`.